# relations null in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to make relationship between 2 tables:

My models:

```
class Modele extends Model 
{
 public function shoe()
 {
     return $this->hasMany('Shoe');
 }
}

class Shoe extends Model 
{
  public function modele()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Modele::class, 'IdModele','id');
  }
}
```

my Controler:

```
class shoeController extends Controller
{
 public function index()
 {

 $shoesList= \App\Shoe::with('modele')->orderBy('idModele')->get();

 return view('shoe.index',compact('shoesList'));
 }
}
```

> When I dd($shoeList) , I have this:

```
#relations: array:1 [▼
    "modele" => null
  ]
```

and if I try to use the params in blade like this:

```
<p>{{$shoe->modele->idGender}}</p>
```

Ihave this error:

> ErrorException thrown with message "Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\laragon\www\ipepsShoes2017\resources\views\shoe\index.blade.php)

I have make other relations between tables in this project with using the same way and they'r working fine.

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure, but when doing the `hasMany`, you have to write the table name, I don't know if that table is `Shoe` of `shoe`. Could you show us your tables structure ?

Comment: return $this->belongsTo(Modele::class, 'idModele','id'); i think i must be small letter nto capse

Comment: here is my table schema :https://photos.app.goo.gl/aGj9ATqhd8qxsMt92 Sorry, i can't upload photos.... the relations between Modele and the other table upper works perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class Modele extends Model 
{
 public function shoe()
 {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Shoe');
 }
}

class Shoe extends Model 
{
  public function modele()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Modele', 'IdModele','id');
  }
}
```

in your view first check {{print_r($shoe->modele)}} if you get object then call param what you need

Comment: when i make print_r($shoe->modele) it only print a 1 . for the other relation who are working, it print all the parameters...

Comment: Just to confirm, bcs @Hamel did not give any explanation about what he fixed or why it would help so you might have missed it: @Fred, your original code uses `return $this->hasMany('Shoe');` which is incorrect.  You need to specify the model like `return $this->hasMany('\App\Shoe');`, or `return $this->hasMany(Shoe::class);`.  Did you fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to write a **foreign key** for hasMany relation to **Modele** Model:

```
class Modele extends Model 
{
    public function shoe()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Shoe', 'IdModele');
    }
}
```

Hope it help you :)